# Using array variable and for loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ar = ["#mob","#tv","#cmp","#prt"]; //div id's to display images
    $(".show").click(function(){
        for(var sh in ar){
            $(sh).css({"display":"block"});
        }
    },5000); 
});
```

i was trying to display images on button click with a delay of 5000, button on click event nothing is been happening.

Comment: jQuery event handlers don't have built-in support for delays. You have to explicitly call `setTimeout()` yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop for in of javascript to far with PHP when you run for (var sh in arr) the sh will start from 0 to 3. That mean your code should be `$(arr[sh]).css({"display": block});`

Comment: No! You should wrapper you function in settimeout function. 
    $('.show').click(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
       for(var sh in ar){
            $(arr[sh]).css({"display":"block"});
        }
      }, 5000);

Answer (score 0):

Place your code that shows your `div` on a function. Let's call the function `showFcn()`.

**showFcn()**:

```
 var ar = ["#mob", "#tv", "#cmp", "#prt"]; //div id's to display images
  for (var sh in ar) {
    $(ar[sh]).show();
  }
 }
```

By the way your sh return a base zero integer, so just call the array elements with `ar[sh]`

In your button `click()` function call `showFcn()` and use `setTimeout()` to add delay.

**click()**:

```
$('#show').click(function() {
  setTimeout(showFcn, 5000);
})
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwm2g09z/33/) for you.

Answer (score 0):

1.) prefer css("display", "block") before show(). jQuery show() has some nasty parts.

And some Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ar = ["#mob","#tv","#cmp","#prt"], timeouts;

    function showElement(){ this.css("display", "block") }
    $(".show").click(function(){
        timeouts = $(ar).map(function(index, id){
            timeouts && clearTimeout(timeouts[index]);
            return setTimeout(showElement.bind($(id)), 5000*index);
        })
    })
});
```